# How to print the address of an integer variable using Fixed statement?

Tags: c#

If I do

```
int n1;
unsafe
{

   int* p1 = &n1;                
   Console.WriteLine("p1: {0}", (int)p1);
}
```

works.

But if I do

```
int n1;
unsafe
{                
  fixed (int* p1 = &n1)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("p1: {0}", (int)p1);
  }
}
```

Compilation error : you cannot use the fixed statement to take the address of an already fixed expression

where I am wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you I think it is because how `fixed` keyword works.- it protects us against moving "managed bytes" inside memory via GarbageCollector (what could make pointer useless). I suppose that integer value is never moved inside memory via GC so it doesn't need to be fixed  (that what compiler error says: "it's alread fixed").

Comment: What did *you* think that the edit between your two code samples was going to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second code you are using `fixed`.

According to **MSDN**, any local variable in an `unsafe` method is already fixed.
And address of the fixed variable cannot be used in a fixed expression. Thsts why you are getting this error.